# Finding all rectangular Ranges within Selection object

Tags: excel, vba

When selecting cells in Excel, it is possible to select multiple rectangular cell Ranges at one time. I am trying to use VBA to determine all the different rectangular Ranges that make up the current Selection. Is there a (preferably simple) way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "rectangular ranges"?  It is possible to select multiple ranges at once, yes.

Comment: To clarify, if I select multiple ranges at once, how do find all the separate ranges I have selected using VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-areas-property-excel).

```
dim a as long
with selection
    debug.print .areas.count
    for a = 1 to .areas.count
        debug.print .areas(a).address(0, 0)
    next a
end with
```